# __argv[1] в CreateFile()

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь получить дескриптор файла с помощью функции `createFile()`. В качестве первого параметра передаю аргумент командной строки:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(__argv[1], FILE_READ_ACCESS, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Но почему-то вижу вот такую ошибку (подчеркивается __argv[1]):

E0167   аргумент типа "char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"

Вот полный код. Пробовал менять стандарт языка, ставить многобайтовую кодировку

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    if (__argc < 2) {
       
    }
    else {
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(__argv[1], FILE_READ_ACCESS, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Тогда вылазит вот это: 
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).
Может в свойствах проекта что-то изменить нужно?

Comment: Изменил CreateFile на CreateFileA

Comment: Собирайте с поддержкой юникода и используйте широкие символы.

Comment: Все, всем спасибо. Получил аргументы через CommandLineToArgvW()

Comment: И ту ошибку тоже решил, изменив подсистему на Windows в св. проекта

Answer (score 0):

`LPCWSTR`  это тоже самое что и `const wchar_t*`. Что бы использовать char* можете использовать функцию `CreateFileA(...)` или в настройках проекта visual studio (если  у тебя она) включить многобайтовую кодировку.